# Issue: The whole page loading instead just the div with .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a layout with 3 columns in `div`s: `cMenu`, `cList` and `cContent`.

In menu, I use this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $("#mMateriasPrimas").on("click", function() {
            $("#cLista").load("materias_primas_lista.php");
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="menu_wrapper">
    <div class="menu_item">
        <a href="materias_primas.php" id="mMateriasPrimas">Matérias primas</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu_hover">
    </div>

<!-- other menu itens following here -->
</div>
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <title></title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/typo.css" rel="stylesheet">    
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
<?php require 'includes/connect_link.php' ; ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <strong>TOP</strong>
    </div><!-- .header-->
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="container">
            <main class="content">
                <strong>MAIN</strong> 
            </main><!-- .content -->
        </div><!-- .container-->
        <div class="left-sidebar" id="cMenu">
            <?php require '_menu.php'; ?>
        </div><!-- .left-sidebar -->
        <div class="right-sidebar" id="cLista">
            <?php // require 'materias_primas_lista.php'; ?>
        </div><!-- .right-sidebar -->
    </div><!-- .middle-->
</div><!-- .wrapper -->
<div class="footer">
    <strong>Footer</strong> 
</div><!-- .footer -->
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on my link, the `cList` `div` receives the correct file and reload the whole page.

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

The *default* action when you click a link is to load the href. You can prevent it by calling `event.preventDefault()`.

```
$("#mMateriasPrimas").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#cLista").load("materias_primas_lista.php");
});
```

Comment: You can also use return: false; in jquery - after it has ran your code of course.

Comment: @samuelmr correct, and not just in jQuery, it works with the native `addEventlistener` too. But this approach has some issues. Returning `false` behaves like `event.preventDefault()` _and_ `event.stopPropagation()` and you often don't want that. You also get inconvenient behaviour if the code in the callback happens to throw an error: it wont reach the `return false` statement and the default behaviour **isn't** cancelled.